# How do I use AWS SDK (Javascript) with VueJS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, vue.js, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

So I'm new to AWS, I created a couple lambdas and download the JS SDK so I can make requests and finally render everything I need on my VueJS project. I'm also using Cognito for authentication.

My questions are: Do I REALLY need to have "apigClientjs" inside my project? 
If there's no other way, how do I make requests?

Yes, I read the whole thing on AWS but I'm still confused.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the package `aws-sdk`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk

Answer (score 0):

API Gateway can *optionally* generate an SDK from your API. No, you don't have to generate or use this SDK.

A very common practice, possibly the most common practice, is to simply front your Lambda functions with API Gateway and then use standard HTTP client libraries, such as [request](https://github.com/request/request) or [axios](https://github.com/axios/axios) to make HTTP requests to your Lambda functions.

Comment: Thank you! The thing is, my boss told my that I have to use SDK because it's a matter of security. I really wanted to make a simple axios, but he said I just can't use the url for x reasons. :/ If what you're trying to say is that I should use something like a normal endpoint, well, not happening. ):

Comment: The generated SDK would itself be making calls to the same API Gateway endpoints under the covers. Both that and an Axios-based client would be SSL.  Obviously, how you authenticate your clients and secure your solution is important. I would go talk to your boss more to better understand the constraints that you're being asked to work with.

Comment: Exactly. I'll talk to him. I just figured out that I can also use Amplify + API Gateway. Well, thank you so much! :D